# Mixing CURL with Objective C

Tags: objective-c, api, macos, curl

I am working with the Let's Crate API, it uses basic Auth and it gives examples on how to use it in CURL:

> Takes `file` and `crate_id` as
>   parameters. `file` is the file data.
>   E.g. curl -F file=@filename.txt -F
>   crate_id=123
>   https://api.letscrate.com/1/files/upload.json

But I have never used CURL before, so how would i make my Mac application when the API involves CURL, I know this is most likely a very simple, question, but I think the fact that I have never used CURL before is confusing me.

I can get it to work using terminal by using this:

```
curl -u <username:password> -F file=@<filename> -F crate_id=<crate ID(number)> https://api.letscrate.com/1/f
```

but i want the user to login, and then just click upload and select the file they want, and then send it, nothing overly hard, i just don't know how to get the CURL to play nice with the Objective C.

Thanks in advance, I hope you can help.

Comment: `curl` is a command. There’s libcurl, a C library which is used by `curl`. However, since you want Objective-C, why not use Cocoa’s `NSURLConnection` instead?

Comment: ah i see, so if i did most things using NSURLConnection it should work fine?

Comment: @Bavarious if you right as an answer i will accept as i think i understand what your saying now,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `libcurl` if you want **CURL** within an Objective-C application. `libcurl` is **CURL**'s library and, since it's written in **C** it plays nicely with Objective-C.